# vega lite - persist null date/time in chart

Tags: vega-lite

How do I persist the `null` in the data on visualization with vega chart while rendering the date/time for data the timestamp. Right now, it looks like `null` data is getting passed as default time of `04:00`

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "data": {
      "values": [
    {
        "x": null,
        "y": "recoPU8F3Asuc8t3n"
    },
    {
        "x": "2017-06-02T07:00:00.000Z",
        "y": "reco056sZzsAd7qVp"
    },
    {
        "x": null,
        "y": "reclQZbw7CiAegm1f"
    },
    {
        "x": "2017-07-14T07:00:00.000Z",
        "y": "recAzUhUdekIdkSVt"
    },
    {
        "x": null,
        "y": "rec0NHCpaRDP9W1pd"
    },
    {
        "x": null,
        "y": "recPYz3QNpXgrmBVy"
    }
]
    },
    "config": {
        "range": {
            "category": [
                "#46bfdd"
            ]
        },
        "legend": {
            "disable": false,
            "labelColor": "#333",
            "labelFontSize": 11,
            "symbolSize": 30,
            "rowPadding": 4,
            "symbolType": "circle",
            "symbolStrokeWidth": 0,
            "titleColor": "#666666",
            "titleFontSize": 11,
            "titlePadding": 10,
            "titleFontWeight": 500,
            "orient": "right"
        },
        "axisY": {
            "tickMinStep": 1,
            "format": "~s",
            "formatType": "number"
        },
        "axis": {
            "domainColor": "#E8E8E8",
            "gridColor": "#E8E8E8",
            "tickColor": "#E8E8E8",
            "grid": true,
            "gridWidth": 1,
            "labelColor": "#666666",
            "labelFontSize": 11,
            "labelLimit": 180,
            "titleColor": "#999999",
            "tickSize": 16,
            "titleFontSize": 13,
            "titlePadding": 10,
            "titleFontWeight": 400,
            "labelPadding": 4,
            "titleLimit": 180
        },
        "autosize": {
            "type": "fit",
            "contains": "padding"
        },
        "axisLeft": {
            "labelFontSize": 11,
            "labelColor": "#999999",
            "labelLimit": 180,
            "titleFontSize": 13,
            "titleFontWeight": 400,
            "titleLimit": 180
        },
        "style": {
            "label": {
                "align": "left",
                "baseline": "middle",
                "dx": 4
            },
            "cell": {
                "stroke": "transparent"
            }
        }
    },
    "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "width": {
            "band": 0.7
        },
        "tooltip": true,
        "cornerRadiusEnd": 3,
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "color": "#4787cd"
    },
    "params": [
        {
            "name": "highlight",
            "select": {
                "type": "point",
                "on": "mouseover"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "select",
            "select": "point"
        }
    ],
    "encoding": {
        "x": {
            "field": "x",
            "type": "nominal",
            "axis": {
                "labelAngle": -90,
                "format": "%I:%M",
                "formatType": "time",
                "title": "Reservation On"
            },
            "sort": {
                "encoding": "x",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            "timeUnit": "hoursminutes"
        },
        "y": {
            "field": "y",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "aggregate": "count",
            "axis": {
                "title": "Number of records"
            }
        },
        "tooltip": [
            {
                "field": "x",
                "title": "Reservation On",
                "format": "%I:%M",
                "formatType": "time",
                "timeUnit": "hoursminutes"
            },
            {
                "field": "y",
                "type": "quantitative",
                "aggregate": "count",
                "title": "Number of records"
            }
        ],
        "fillOpacity": {
            "condition": [
                {
                    "param": "select",
                    "value": 1
                }
            ],
            "value": 0.3
        },
        "strokeWidth": {
            "condition": [
                {
                    "param": "select",
                    "empty": false,
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "param": "highlight",
                    "empty": false,
                    "value": 1
                }
            ],
            "value": 0
        }
    },
    "transform": [
    ],
    "height": 372,
    "width": 536
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by replacing your `"format"` with an appropriate `"labelExpr"`:

```
"axis": {
  "labelAngle": -90,
  "labelExpr": "isValid(datum.value) ? timeFormat(datum.value, '%I:%M') : 'null'",
  "title": "Reservation On"
}
```